# How should I deal with NaN values when the data isn't categorical and determining them isn't practical?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, nan, data-cleaning, feature-engineering

I'm currently doing the house prices kaggle, and there is a feature of the year which the garage was built in. There are houses without a garage, so the feature is NaN for them.

How should I deal with this situation? Imputing those values with 0 doesn't make sense to me, as it will influence the entire feature. Mean also doesn't make much sense, but I really don't know.

I'm just not sure it makes sense to replace those NaN values with a number, because when there's no garage there also can't be a year it was built in.

Comment: Those aren't the only methods for imputation, there are [lot more](https://towardsdatascience.com/6-different-ways-to-compensate-for-missing-values-data-imputation-with-examples-6022d9ca0779) you can try.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript there is a function called isNaN(val) which will return true if val is a NaN and false if not. You can use this to determine if the value is NaN or not. You need not modify your data. Does this help?

The reason you are getting NaN is because the result of your calculation is Not a Number (i.e NaN)

Comment: Thank you, but it won't really solve my problem because this solution will only tell if there is a specified year for the garage or not, and will basically ignore the year itself.

Comment: If there is a Garage, there will be a year and isNaN will return false. If isNaN is true it means there is no year and hence no garage. If you are creating this data and not fetching it from somewhere better not use NaN.

Comment: I get that, but there will still be NaN values in the year column. I must fill them if I want to use the feature, and I don't know what is the appropriate way to do so without the imputed values messing the entire feature's meaning up.

Comment: Replace NaN with a blank string ''